# Generic Vector Class Implementation

Tags: c++, templates, vector, generic-programming

I want to implement numerical `Vector` which has several numerical operations.

I used template to define generic version of vector.

But implementation should be different with concrete implementation like `Vector3`.

For example, `+` operation would look like these.

**Vector3 implementation**

```
Vector3 operator+(const Vector3& vec3) const{
    return Vector3(data[0]+vec3.data[0], data[1]+vec3.data[1], data[2]+vec3.data[2]);
}
```

**template implementation**

```
GenericVector operator+(const GenericVector<T,N>& vec) const{
    GenericVector temp = *this;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    { 
        temp.data[i] += vec.data[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Now that we cannot know how many `data` it would have, we cannot define constructor like `Vector3(x,y,z)`. That's why I introduced for loop in `+ operator` overloading.

Actually when it comes to appearance of codes, `Vector3` implementation looks better. But it cannot be scaled to different size vectors.

Template's implementation looks less nicer than that of `Vector3`. But  template version can easily scaled to many size vectors by doing like this.

```
typedef GenericVector<double, 3> Vector3d;
typedef GenericVector<double, 6> Vector6d;
```

**I'm not used to template of C++. Is there any one who can point problem of my implementation or understandings?**

My question is that in implementation of `+ operator` in template version, is the choice of introducing for loop for accommodating unknown integer `N` **right** or **the only choice**?

To simple one question,

**Can I avoid for loop in `+ operator`?**

This is parts of my codes.

```
template <typename T, int N>
class GenericVector{
protected:
    T data[N];
public:
    GenericVector()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            data[i] = static_cast<T>(0);
        }
    }

    GenericVector operator+(const GenericVector<T,N>& vec) const{
        GenericVector temp = *this;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            temp.data[i] += vec.data[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //...
};
```

Comment: So what is the question?  Is it not working or are you asking if this is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to initialize `data` to `0` in a loop. All you need is `GenericVector(): data() {}`. And you don't need the template parameters in the `operator+` parameter. This will do: `GenericVector operator+(const GenericVector& vec) const`. Other than that, it looks OK. But I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Also, you should probably implement `GenericVector& operator+=(const GenericVector&)` and use that in `operator+`.

Comment: Thanks, @juanchopanza. I did implement '+=' but omit here for the sake of simplicity:D.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to avoid the loops in the various operations is to *not* store an array but use inheritance and specialization to deal with the different number of arguments. Something along the lines of this:

```
template <typename T, int Size> class GVector;
template <typename T>
class GVector<T, 0> {
public:
    GVector() {}
    GVector& operator+= (GVector const&) { return *this; }
    GVector  operator+ (GVector const& other) const {
        return GVector() += other;
    }
    // ...
};
template <typename T, int Size>
class GVector: public GVector<T, Size - 1> {
    T value;
public:
    GVector(): GVector<T, Size - 1>(), value() {}
    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    GVector(T const& head, Tail const&... tail)
        : GVector<T, Size - 1>(tail...)
        , value(head) {
    }
    GVector& operator+= (GVector const& other) {
        this->value += other.value;
        this->GVector<T, Size - 1>::operator+= (other);
        return *this;
    }
    GVector operator+ (GVector const& other) const {
        return GVector(*this) += other;
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I think, you are missing the specialization for vector of size 1.

Comment: Not sure this is an actual gain of, well, anything.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to understand your answer. BTW, what is `...` in `GVector` constructor? I've never seen those.

Comment: @JaeJunLEE, I suppose, you do not really need to follow this example at this stage. Dietmar is kinda trolling.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, oh yes. I somehow overlooked the whole code. As for trolling, taking into account alleged level of proficiency of OP, and the level of proficiency required to understand the answer, there is a huge gap.

Comment: Dear @DietmarKühl, can you suggest one usage for your code?

Answer (score 1):

There's generally a tradeoff when making code more generic: you reduce code duplication when you can reuse your generic code with different parameters but it usually means somewhat more complex code than the non-generic version and also limits opportunities for optimization. Better compilers and newer C++ features help reduce the tradeoffs but they still exist.

To answer your question, yes it is possible to create a generic vector class that doesn't use `for` loops to iterate over the elements of the vector. Using `for` loops is an acceptable implementation, however in my experiments with a [generic vector class](https://github.com/mattnewport/mathlib/blob/master/MathLib/include/vector.h) I opted not to use them because I found with my compiler that they were not fully unrolled even in optimized builds.

Note - this code is mostly an experiment to investigate the tradeoffs in building a generic vector class. I wouldn't necessarily advocate using a design like this in production.

C++11 [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) offer a solution to your constructor problem although there are certain issues that come along with them:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class Vector {
public:
    static const size_t dimension = N;

    Vector() = default;
    Vector(const Vector&) = default;

    template <typename... Ts>
    Vector(T t, Ts&&... ts)
        : aw({t, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == N - 1, "Constructor must be passed N initializers.");
    }

private:
    struct ArrayWrapper {
        T e_[N];
    } aw;  // ArrayWrapper lets us initialize in constructor initializer
};
```

They can also be used to avoid looping in operators:

```
template <size_t I, typename F, typename... Args>
auto apply(F f, Args&&... args) {
    return f(args.e(I)...);
}

template <typename F, size_t... Is, typename... Args>
auto apply(F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&&... args) {
    using vec = std::common_type_t<Args...>;
    using resvec = Vector<decltype(apply<0>(f, args...)), vec::dimension>;
    return resvec{apply<Is>(f, args...)...};
}

template <typename F, typename... Args>
inline auto memberwise(F f, const Args&... args) {
    using vec = std::common_type_t<Args...>;
    return apply(f, std::make_index_sequence<vec::dimension>{}, args...);
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
inline Vector<T, N> operator+(const Vector<T, N>& a, const Vector<T, N>& b) {
    return memberwise(std::plus<>{}, a, b);
}
```

In my experiments with this approach I found this produces good code in optimized builds with my compiler but it adds quite a lot of overhead in non-optimized builds, more than using a `for` loop.